# SQL SELECT with DISTINCT on multiple columns

Tags: sql, database

**In SQL multiple fields may also be added with DISTINCT clause. DISTINCT will eliminate those rows where all the selected fields are identical.**

SQL Code:

```
SELECT agent_code, ord_amount, cust_code, ord_num
FROM orders 
WHERE agent_code='A002';
```

ORD_NUM ORD_AMOUNT ADVANCE_AMOUNT ORD_DATE  CUST_CODE       AGENT_CODE

---

```
200114       3500           2000 15-AUG-08 C00002          A008
200122       2500            400 16-SEP-08 C00003          A004
200118        500            100 20-JUL-08 C00023          A006
200119       4000            700 16-SEP-08 C00007          A010
200121       1500            600 23-SEP-08 C00008          A004
200130       2500            400 30-JUL-08 C00025          A011
200134       4200           1800 25-SEP-08 C00004          A005
200108       4000            600 15-FEB-08 C00008          A004
200103       1500            700 15-MAY-08 C00021          A005
200105       2500            500 18-JUL-08 C00025          A011
200109       3500            800 30-JUL-08 C00011          A010
200101       3000           1000 15-JUL-08 C00001          A008
200111       1000            300 10-JUL-08 C00020          A008
200104       1500            500 13-MAR-08 C00006          A004
200106       2500            700 20-APR-08 C00005          A002
200125       2000            600 10-OCT-08 C00018          A005
200117        800            200 20-OCT-08 C00014          A001
200123        500            100 16-SEP-08 C00022          A002
200120        500            100 20-JUL-08 C00009          A002
200116        500            100 13-JUL-08 C00010          A009
200124        500            100 20-JUN-08 C00017          A007
200126        500            100 24-JUN-08 C00022          A002
200129       2500            500 20-JUL-08 C00024          A006
200127       2500            400 20-JUL-08 C00015          A003
200128       3500           1500 20-JUL-08 C00009          A002
200135       2000            800 16-SEP-08 C00007          A010
200131        900            150 26-AUG-08 C00012          A012
200133       1200            400 29-JUN-08 C00009          A002
200100       1000            600 08-JAN-08 C00015          A003
200110       3000            500 15-APR-08 C00019          A010
200107       4500            900 30-AUG-08 C00007          A010
200112       2000            400 30-MAY-08 C00016          A007
200113       4000            600 10-JUN-08 C00022          A002
200102       2000            300 25-MAY-08 C00012          A012
```

Output:

```
AGENT_CODE ORD_AMOUNT CUST_CODE     ORD_NUM
---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
A002             2500 C00005         200106
A002              500 C00022         200123
A002              500 C00009         200120
A002              500 C00022         200126
A002             3500 C00009         200128
A002             1200 C00009         200133
A002             4000 C00022         200113
```

Want To Optimize My Query

Comment: What if there was an extra row of (9, d, 12-02-2016)? What would you expect the output to be then?

Comment: please don't spam tag

Answer (score 2):

It appears that you want to retain each distinct name which occurs the earliest.  One option uses a subquery:

```
SELECT ID, Name, Date
FROM yourTable t1
WHERE Date = (SELECT MIN(Date) FROM yourTable t2 WHERE t2.Name = t1.Name)
```

Note this solution would return more than one record per name group should there be a tie for two records having the minimum date.  But the sample data does not seem to imply that this would happen.

Comment: @AnkitAgrawal What is your logic for wanting `1,3,7,8` ... this is not clear.

Comment: as per in given upper question

Comment: @AnkitAgrawal You won't answer the question, I won't edit my query, it's that simple.

Answer (score 2):

Is this you want?

```
select min(id),name, min(date) from table_1  group by name
```

Comment: But what would happen if the minimum ID does not coincide with the minimum date for a given name group?

Comment: But in the given sample, the date is in asc order.

Comment: Yes, I agree that you are probably OK for this data set, but in general it could be an issue.  To fix it, you could first use a subquery to find the minimum IDs, and then join back to the original table.

Comment: no I just want unique in both first column and second column not an issue of date asc or desc.etc but I am surprised this is issue of many people but why people vote it negatively.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are looking for the earliest date for each Name. This query will achieve that. It will group it by Name and give the minimum date for that Name.

```
SELECT Name,MIN(Date) FROM table_1 GROUP BY Name
```